# Overlap affecting colors

Tags: adobe-illustrator, background, overlay

See this image:

[image]

I really don't know how to describe this but I'm getting a weird overlayed color from the magenta waves when I put them over my background.

As you can see I have the blue rectangle and then I want to put the magenta wavy lines on top of it but instead I get this weird overlay effect as if the waves were below them.

I tried making a separate layer and put the background at the bottom, I've tried to send the rectangle to the back, send it backward, etc.

What is wrong with it? Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possible causes...

1. There is a **blending mode** applied to some of your objects. Select the objects (Magenta) and check the **Appearance Panel** to see if any blending mode is set and reset the mode to `Normal`. You can also check the **Transparency Panel** to see if a blending mode is set.
2. The objects are set to **overprint** and you have **Overprint
   Preview** on. Select the object and check the **Attributes Panel** and see if `Overprint` is ticked there - Untick it.
3. (This one is unlikely based upon your sample image - but for others, it could be valid.) You used Illustrator's `Simulate Colored Paper` option in the **Document Setup**. Don't use that option, just draw a box and send it to back to simulate colored stock. Then remove or hide the background before outputting the artwork.

Odds are *very high* that the issue is #1 above.

Beyond this, it would take a screenshot of the Layers and Appearance panels *with* the object selected, or direct file examination to determine why colors are interacting.

Comment: Thank you, that was it. Apparently I somehow managed to apply a blending mode